# disablinging autorecover option for powepoint

Tags: powershell, powerpoint

I am not able to find the correct property/method to disable the auto recover option for powerpoint. For Excel and word its as below

For excel this will do it
$wb.EnableAutoRecover = $False

and for word 
$word.Options.SaveInterval = 0

Any idea what I need to do for powerpoint? There is an 'Option's read only property.

Comment: +1. Good question. I haven't ever seen this for PowerPoint.

Answer (score 1):

Most of PowerPoint's Options settings are stored in the registry, usually:

HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Office\xx.0\PowerPoint\Options

You can leave this open in Regedit, change an option in PPT then refresh Regedit to see what's changed.

In this case check:

FrequencyToSaveAutoRecoveryInfo

PowerPoint reads the options settings at startup, writes them out as the user makes changes and again at shutdown but never reads them from the registry again during a session.  In other words, if you change the settings while PPT is running:

1) It'll have no effect, and
2) PowerPoint will overwrite your changes when it quits

You need to make any necessary changes while PPT is shut down.