# Vsto PowerPoint 2007

Tags: interop, ms-office, office-interop, powerpoint-2007

I have been ask to develop a Add-in to PowerPoint 2007 using VSTO.

I need to disable AutoRover/AutoSave from code only in PowerPoint, is that possible ?

I have found it possible in Excel and Word.

Excel: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel.autorecover.time%28v=office.14%29.aspx
this.Application.AutoRecover.Enabled = false;

Word: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.word.options.saveinterval%28v=office.11%29.aspx
this.Application.Options.SaveInterval = 0;

I have search the Internet for information with regardes to this. Some say it is not possible, and some that I need to set the value in Windows Registry before I start PowerPoint 2007. Does anyone have some information, or some proof that PowerPoint does have that options.

Thx for taking the time to read.

**UPDATE 11-21-2012**

This post are saying, that we can use this setting
HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Office\xx.0\PowerPoint\Options
But I cant find that one in Windows Registry.

[disablinging autorecover option for powepoint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5464075/disablinging-autorecover-option-for-powepoint)

Answer (score 0):

Some app defaults are not written to the registry; if you change the default, you get the reg entry.

For example, in Options, Save, if you remove the check next to "Save AutoRecover Information ..." you'l find

SaveAutoRecoveryInfo 
with a value of 0

in the registry as you've indicated (substitute the correct version of PPT for xx.0)

So you can either use PPT to create the entry for you or you can create it yourself manually or via code.

Note that for this to work, you MUST make the change while PowerPoint is not running.